# Saving image into mysql database- JSP and Servlets

Tags: mysql, forms, jsp, servlets

I am newbie to JSP and servlets. I am trying to save a text and an image in the database.

```
<input type="file" class="text-box" id="select_photo">
```

In the javascript, i am calling the servlet to save these. With the id, i am able to pass the text to the servlet from javascript and then save to database. Can anyone please guide how to pass the image?? Does javascript allow base 64 encoding so that we can encode and save as an encoded string and save in the database?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the canvas element in `html5` and in javascript using encoding the url

```
function saveDataURL(a) {
    var postData = "imageName="+encodeURIComponent(a);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST",'uploadPhoto.cgi',true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.send(postData);    
}
```

sends a encoded base64 to the servlet.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, what is 'a' the parameter here? Get element by id?

Comment: it is the `javascript` code to send the image in the encoded form using ajax